# How to prevent the page from reloading when the form is submitted?

Tags: php, html

When I submit my HTML form, I want PHP to get the value of the input but whenever I submit my HTML form, it reloads the page. How to prevent this?? 
Thanks In Advance.

My Code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q1" name="Q1"><br>
    <input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q2" name="Q2"><br>
    <input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q3" name="Q3">
    <input type="submit" type="button" id="submit2" name="submit2">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $input1 = $_POST['Q1'];
    $input2 = $_POST['Q2'];
    $input3 = $_POST['Q3'];
    echo $input1;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why multiple `type` in `input` ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at AJAX? This can be used to call another .php file, and submit the data of our form, without any page refresh.

Comment: What do you mean by reloading?  If you submit your form to a different page, it will not 'reload'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using AJAX. With Ajax, web applications can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

The exact code for your page would be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });

    });

  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q1" name="Q1"><br>
    <input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q2" name="Q2"><br>
    <input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q3" name="Q3">
    <input type="submit" type="button" id="submit2" name="submit2">
</form>
```

PHP: post.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
  $input1 = $_POST['Q1'];
  $input2 = $_POST['Q2'];
  $input3 = $_POST['Q3'];
  echo $input1;
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how should I do this if my PHP code is in the file as the ajax code??

Comment: You'll need to just create the php as an external page

Answer (score 3):

You need ajax

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="time" value="00:00:00.00"><br>
      <input name="date" value="0000-00-00"><br>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

post.php

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);
if ($_POST['date']) {
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $time = $_POST['time'];
  echo '<h1>' . $date . '---' . $time . '</h1>';
}
else {

}
?>
```

Comment: beat me to it. I was literally typing the exact same code. This is the right answer

Comment: @LemuelBotha it as 'an' answer.  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/57056/is-there-really-a-right-answer

Comment: I agree, after really reading his answer I see that he actually just copied it from an answer on another question without editing to fit this question

Comment: @LemuelBotha and as such the original answer could have been linked to.

Answer (score -3):

In javascript, you could do `e.preventDefault()` by `e` is the event

Hope this helps

Comment: The form wouldn't get submitted then.

Comment: I suppose you could call `POST` event via javascript in the background using AJAX

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but that's not in your answer :)

Comment: This is not really an answer as it ultimately will not solve OP's issue

Comment: You can send the data from the form to your php file and then update the element in the page dynamically